# including a interactive 3D figure with knitr

Tags: html, r, knitr, rgl, r-markdown

Using `knitr` it is possible to embed a `rgl` 3D graphics in a html document from a `Rmarkdown` source file:

````
```{r setup}
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(rgl = hook_rgl)
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
```

```{r, rgl=TRUE}
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

But the 3D graphic is not interactive in the html document. Is it possible to get an interactive 3D graphic ? The `writeWebGL()` function of the `rgl` package creates a html file with an interactive 3D graphic, is there a way to include directly this html code with Rmarkdown ? Otherwise how to include this html code manually ?

### Update 24/06/2013

Here is an example that does not work today (the 3D graphic does not appear in Chrome):

- the [Rmd source file](https://gist.github.com/stla/5870638), which is very basic:

  ````
  ```{r setup}
  library(rgl)
  knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
  ```
  ```{r, webgl=TRUE}
  M <- rbind(
    c(0,0,0),
    c(-1,4,0),
    c(4,9,0),
    c(6,3,0)
    )
    points3d(M,col='red')
  ```
  ```{r}
  sessionInfo()
  ```
  ````

  I have knitted this file with the RStudio "knit" button in two situations using different versions of `rgl` and `knitr` packages (but this is surely due to the `rgl` package because the problem occurs with the output of the `writeWebGL` function) :
- old versions with R-2.15.2 : [source file](https://gist.github.com/stla/5870681) and [html rendering](http://pagist.github.io/?5870681). And the [html file generated by `writeWebGL` with rgl_0.93.928](https://gist.github.com/stla/5871039). For me it works well (there are just 4 red points in the 3D plot... not easy to see on my dirty screen but I see them).
- latest versions with R-2.15.3 : [source file](https://gist.github.com/stla/5870653) and [html rendering](http://pagist.github.io/?5870653). And the [html file generated by `writeWebGL` with rgl_0.93.935](https://gist.github.com/stla/5871051). For me it doesn't work: the 3D plot is not visible. I use Windows 7 and it doesn't work with Chrome,  neither with Firefox.

### Edit 28/06/2013

The problem raised by the 24/06 update has nothing to do with `knitr`. I have rephrased it in this post: [WebGL rendering with rgl 0.93.935 R package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17365709/1100107)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I [added](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/1f18ebbd22266fe988c05dff0ccad440e7f7442c) a new hook `hook_webgl()` in **knitr**, which was incorporated into **rgl** later. Here is an example:

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

```{r testgl, webgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

Comment: Thank you Yihui ! But I have tried the command `install.packages('knitr', repos = 'http://www.rforge.net/')` and I think this has not installed the latest version (`Error in knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl) : object 'hook_webgl' not found`)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Right, there is a one-day lag for building binaries; make sure you see the latest build here http://rforge.net/knitr/files/ Otherwise just try to install from source `install.packages('knitr', repos='http://www.rforge.net/', type='source')`, but RForge has problems with building my package under Windows, and you can also try `install.packages("knitr", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: Thank you Yihui, that works well with `install.packages("knitr", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: Hello Yihui. Please see the rendering here http://stla.overblog.com/including-an-interactive-3d-rgl-graphic-in-a-html-report-with-knitr1 (it works with Chrome only for me). It would be great if we could conveniently include multiple 3G graphics into a single hmtl report.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I just released knitr 1.1 to CRAN. For multiple plots in one page, I think it is possible in theory -- I did think about it when I was writing `hook_webgl()`, but I did not succeed because I was confused by the `prefix` argument in `rgl::writeWebGL()` which did not work as I expected. Anyway, feel free to file an issue here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues I'll take anther look when I have got time.

Comment: Ok Yihui, but I firstly need to create an account on github. I will do it later.

Comment: FYI Devtools + windows should no longer need rtools installed unless the package has C source code

Comment: @hadley that is nice, but `knitr` still needs `make` in the age of R 2.x; after 3.0, it will be a pure R package, hence easy to install even under Windows

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent someone else has reported the issue for you https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/494 and it is fixed now

Comment: Thank you Yihui! I have just tried but the same problem occurs - I guess the new version for Windows is not available yet :)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, from time to time RForge fails to build the Windows version, but you can always install from source: `install.packages('knitr', repos='http://www.rforge.net/', type='source')`

Comment: Right, Yihui ! http://stla.overblog.com/including-an-interactive-3d-rgl-graphic-with-knitr Now it works with Firefox too.

Comment: Hello Yihui. Today I run the following code and the 3D plot does not appear in the html rendering : ```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

```{r, webgl=TRUE}
M <- rbind(
  c(0,0,0),
  c(-1,4,0),
  c(4,9,0),
  c(6,3,0)
  )
  points3d(M,col='red')
```

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it does appear when I run your code; please update your original post with `library(knitr); library(rgl); sessionInfo()`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent with the same version of knitr, I can see the 3D plot in Chrome, but I'm under Ubuntu and R 3.0.1. Please post the HTML source of the html file generated from RStudio(? or? you did not mention) on pastebin.com

Comment: Yes, from RStudio. The html code is here http://pastebin.com/HxGMhtME I have checked that this is not due to the Canvas.js file.

Comment: @Yihui I have knitted the Rmd source file of the article I wrote on my blog. The generated html file has some differences with the old one. This is surely due to an update of `rgl`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I still cannot reproduce your problem. I used the same version of rgl and produced the same HTML file as yours. I can see the 3D plot in Google Chrome (Version 27.0.1453.93) under Ubuntu. If you see differences between the two versions of rgl, please post the results from `diff`. Or try a different web browser. It does not sound like a problem of rgl.

Comment: Yihui, I have just knitted the [preliminary version](http://pagist.github.io/?5861876) of my new article with my R.2.15.2 installation which contains an older version of `rgl` and this works very well. But it doesn't work with R.2.15.3 which contains the last version of `rgl`. I don't understand what is `diff` ?

Comment: Yihui, tomoroow I'll post two gists, one for each version.

Comment: `diff` is a *nix command to compare two files and calculate the difference; if you do not know that, just post the two HTML files and I can run `diff`

Comment: Yihui, I've asked to some people to try. It seems that this doesn't work for Windows users. Should I report this problem to the author of `rgl` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, please report to Duncan. Both versions work for me under Ubuntu.

Comment: Yihui, the bug has been fixed by @havarc :-)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Nice! I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: And this, my friends, is the problem with link-based answers

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed since this question and answer were written in 2013.  Nowadays I wouldn't recommend using `rgl=TRUE` or `webgl=TRUE`.  Instead, use the following approaches:

The easiest approach is to have a setup code chunk containing

````
   ```{r include=FALSE}
   options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
   rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)
   ```
````

With this setup, plots will appear automatically.  If you run several commands to produce a plot, only the final version will appear.  (Some functions in other packages don't cooperate with this scheme and nothing will appear; for those, you can trigger it by making a call to `rgl::lowlevel()` in the chunk once the graphic is complete.)

If you don't want the automatic inclusion, then use

````
   ```{r include=FALSE}
   options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
   rgl::setupKnitr()
   ```
````

With this option you make an explicit call to `rglwidget()` whenever you want a graphic to display.

There are several `knitr` chunk options supported:  `rgl.newwindow, rgl.closewindow, rgl.margin, snapshot, dpi, fig.retina, fig.width, fig.height, fig.keep, fig.hold, fig.beforecode, dev`; they are described in the `?rgl::setupKnitr` help topic.