# How to export an interactive rgl 3D Plot to share or publish?

Tags: r, 3d, pca, rgl

I have made an interactive 3D plot in R using the rgl package. I would like to be able to send it (and keep it interactive) to a colleague so she can present it (rotate it) in a meeting on her laptop. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code I used to generate the plot:

And this is the plot:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(pcaGB$x[,1:3], col=gbMeta2.5K$gbColor, type='s', size=1)
```

[image]

I am then using this code to export it to HTML using writeWebGL, but without any luck so far:

```
browseURL(paste("file://", writeWebGL(dir=file.path("~/Documents/", "webGL"), width=700), sep=""))
```

This is what I get back in a browser window:

[image]

I've also tried using just writeWebGL but that creates a folder in the directory with an index.html file that opens the same image as above in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to still be interactive upon exporting, so that she can rotate it herself.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it doesn't seem to be working. And also I don't know how I would share it with her if it did ... ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the code I've been trying to use writeWebGL to my question. It just opens a browser window with an error :(

Comment: try making the figure, then just `writeWebGL()` should create a folder webGL in your working directory with the stuff in it

Comment: Still not working. I tried with just `writeWebGL()`, but that made a folder in the directory with a CanvasMatrix.jl file, an index.html file and a snapshot.png that looks like a close up of one of the edges of the cube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the interactive plot to html using knitr. For the details see: [including a interactive 3D figure with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879210/including-a-interactive-3d-figure-with-knitr).