# saving 3D plot as html

Tags: html, r, save, rgl

I drew a 3D plot with plot3d function using rgl packagein R

```
plot3d(x[,1:3], type= 's', col = y[,6], size= 2)
```

however I cant save it as html
I tried knitr and writeWebGl , but without any success.

```
knit_hooks$set(rgl = hook_rgl)
```

also this code only open an empty html

```
browseURL(paste("file://", writeWebGL(dir=file.path(tempdir(), "webGL"), 
      width=500), sep=""))
```

my question is how i can save my 3d plot in html?

Comment: Did you follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904198/how-to-export-an-interactive-rgl-3d-plot-to-share-or-publish ?

Comment: Thank you @yeahman269 yes i followed,  this code 'knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)' run without error but showes nothing. and this one 'browseURL(paste("file://", writeWebGL(dir=file.path(tempdir(), "webGL"), 
                                      width=500), sep=""))' opens a browser says "You must enable Javascript to view this page properly" however it is enable. so i couldnt solve the issue yet.