# interactive 3D plots in markdown file - not working anymore?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rgl

a couple of months ago, i wanted to embed a 3D interactive plot in a markdown file.
looking at previous questions, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879210/including-a-interactive-3d-figure-with-knitr), which worked great (thanks for that, BTW).

however, when i tried to re do it again today- i can only zoom in and out with the mouse and can not rotate the graph. i've also checked the markdown file that i made before and used to work and i also get the same issue. this happens in Rstudio "browser" thingy (the thing that pops up after you knit) and also in Chrome.

here are two examples, one with rgl package and one with car package, both not working for me (both used to work):

## 1

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```
```{r, rgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

## 2

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```
```{r testgl, webgl=TRUE}
library(car)
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
scatter3d(x, y, z , point.col = "blue", surface=FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "C", zlab = "")
```
````

i'm using Rstudio 0.99.489, i've updated all the packages and using R 3.2.3

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] car_2.1-1     rgl_0.95.1441

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3        lattice_0.20-33    digest_0.6.9       MASS_7.3-45        grid_3.2.3         MatrixModels_0.4-1
 [7] nlme_3.1-122       SparseM_1.7        minqa_1.2.4        nloptr_1.0.4       Matrix_1.2-3       rmarkdown_0.9.2   
[13] splines_3.2.3      lme4_1.1-10        tools_3.2.3        parallel_3.2.3     pbkrtest_0.4-6     yaml_2.1.13       
[19] mgcv_1.8-9         htmltools_0.3      nnet_7.3-11        quantreg_5.19
```

thank you all for helping

Answer (score 5):

After contacting Dr. Yihui Xie (`knitr` developer) and Professor John Fox (`car` developer) I think that I can post two options to get around the problem.

**Note**: These solutions are all the result of the work done by Dr. Xie and Professor Fox and I would like to use this platform to thank them both for taking time to answer my question.

### Frst option (no update needed)

Calling `next3d()` immediately before the call to `scatter3d()` creates a plot that can be zoomed and rotated in HTML. Consider this simple code as an example:

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

```{r, webgl=TRUE}
library(car)
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
next3d()
scatter3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

### Second option (package update needed)

Professor Fox has modified the `scatter3d()` function to call `next3d()` on its own (instead of `rgl.clear()`) thus eliminating the need to manually call `next3d()` before every call to `scatter3d()`. I have tested it out on my windows machine and can report that it works.

To install the modified package use:

```
install.packages("car", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: Both solutions don't seem to fix my problem. Could you check your code?

Comment: fixed the code.
can you check again? it is working for me now. 
i used plot3d() instead of scatter3d() and didn't use webgl=TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

try using threejs

It works without problems and IMO looks better

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(threejs)
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
scatterplot3js(x, y, z,  color=rainbow(1000), renderer="canvas")
```
````

Comment: thank you for helping!
it does work but i need the additional features in the "car" package - regression surface, clustering , etc'  

i've looked at the package but, as of now, can't seem to figure out if this package provide this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try installing the rglwidget package    `install.packages('rglwidget')`

Next, your example 1 seems to work when a space is added between code chunks

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

```{r, webgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

I'm unsure as to why the example two is no longer working though

Comment: thank you for helping but installing rglwidget doesn't seem to help. 

are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, I find it interesting that if I remove the newline between the code chunks this non longer works on my machine though

Comment: Generally I'd suggest using the `rgl::setupKnitr` function rather than calling `knit_hooks()` yourself.  The interface between `rgl` and `knitr` has been changing quite a bit recently; `setupKnitr` should keep up with the changes.