# knitr bookdown::gitbook and webgl: rotation does not work properly

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rgl, r-car

I have the following Rmd file:

````
---
output: bookdown::gitbook
---

```{r include=FALSE}
rgl::setupKnitr()
```

```{r testing1,webgl=TRUE}
with(attitude,
  car::scatter3d(x = rating, z = complaints, y = learning)
)
```

```{r testing2,webgl=TRUE}
with(attitude,
  car::scatter3d(x = rating, z = complaints, y = learning)
)
```
````

When I knit this file, it produces and HTML file containing two, identical 3D interactive scatterplots. Both scatterplots look like they should, but the *second* scatterplot does not rotate properly. It will not rotate horizontally in depth correctly (eg, around the vertical axis).

In case it helps, you can find the HTML output of the knit here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3usmtes7n54t6q/Untitled.html.zip?dl=0

I have done all the following, none of which have fixed the problem:

1. Updated all packages with `update.packages()`.
2. Installed the development version of `bookdown`.
3. Installed the development version of `knitr`.
4. Tried the solution here (didn't work): [interactive 3D plots in markdown file - not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174359/interactive-3d-plots-in-markdown-file-not-working-anymore)

I have noted the following:

- If I change the `output` to `html_document` I do not have the problem (I'm debugging the problem in a `bookdown::gitbook` though, so that knowledge does not directly help me).
- In the Firefox (77.0.1, 64-bit) javascript error console there is an error: `TypeError: li[0] is undefined / plugin-bookdown.js:152:43` (which appears to have something to do with the table of contents and scrolling?)

Here is the output of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bookdown_0.19.4  fansi_0.4.1      digest_0.6.25    crayon_1.3.4    
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1 evaluate_0.14    rlang_0.4.6      cli_2.0.2       
 [9] rstudioapi_0.11  rmarkdown_2.3    tools_4.0.0      glue_1.4.1      
[13] xfun_0.14        yaml_2.2.1       rsconnect_0.8.16 compiler_4.0.0  
[17] htmltools_0.5.0  knitr_1.28.7
```

In addition, here are the versions of some other relevant packages:

```
> installed.packages()[c("rgl","mgcv","car"),"Version"]
       rgl       mgcv        car 
"0.100.54"   "1.8-31"    "3.0-8"
```

**Edit to add more detail**

I have the same problem while using `rgl::persp3d`, so it isn't specific to `car::scatter3d`. The HTML from the Rmd file below uses only `rgl` but exhibits the same behavior.

````
---
output: bookdown::gitbook
---

```{r include=FALSE}
rgl::setupKnitr()

x <- seq(-10, 10, length = 30)
y <- x
f <- function(x, y) { r <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
z <- outer(x, y, f)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1
```

```{r testing1,webgl=TRUE}
rgl::persp3d(x, y, z, aspect = c(1, 1, 0.5), col = "lightblue",
        xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Sinc( r )", 
        polygon_offset = 1)
```

```{r testing2,webgl=TRUE}
rgl::persp3d(x, y, z, aspect = c(1, 1, 0.5), col = "lightblue",
        xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Sinc( r )", 
        polygon_offset = 1)
```
````

Comment: `car` is known not to use `rgl` properly.  You should submit a bug report to its author.

Comment: I didn't mention it above (I will edit to add it) but I've had the same problem with rgl::persp3d.

Comment: I had the same suspicion, though what gave me pause is that  1) only one axis of rotation is affected, and 2) I *think* the js error is related to bookdown::gitbook being used "out of context", and I originally saw this problem with no corresponding javascript error (I simplified the example a great deal for this; I originally noticed it here: https://richarddmorey.github.io/cardiffPlacementStats/higher-order-regression-analyses.html#visualization-4). I included the reference to the javascript error out of completeness; may be a red herring.

Comment: What appears to be happening is that `rgl` miscalculates the position of the mouse click in the second display.  The `x` coordinate looks okay, but the `y` coordinate is way off, so it acts as though the click happened much further up the page than it really did.  I'll see if I can work out why it's different than with `html_document`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in `rgl`, that was using an obsolete method to compute the location of mouse clicks relative to objects in scenes.  It worked in an `html_document`, but not with `bookdown::gitbook`.

The development version (0.102.6) of `rgl` has fixed this, but it contains some really major changes, and a few other things are still broken by them:  in particular using the `webgl=TRUE` chunk option.  If you want to use the devel version, you should use explicit calls to `rglwidget()` in each chunk, or if you want to try out the new stuff, use `rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)` and just treat `rgl` graphics like base graphics, controlled by chunk options `fig.keep` etc.

**Edited to add:**  version 0.102.7 fixes the known `webgl=TRUE` issue.

Comment: Thanks. Having trouble installing the development version due to it thinking I don't have X11, but I've posted over in the RForge forum just to keep this focused on the other issue.

Comment: I've confirmed that this works; thanks for the help (and rgl in general).