# Knitting R HTML help documents with rgl examples

Tags: r, knitr, rgl

`knitr` provides a neat function to compile R HTML help documents which contain evaluated examples embedded in the document. This is achieved with the `knit_rd` function, which has some simple input arguments

```
packageVersion('knitr')
[1] ‘1.12.3’

args(knit_rd)
function (pkg, links = tools::findHTMLlinks(), frame = TRUE)
```

However, when the examples contain `rgl` code for interactive graphics these do not get embedded in the document (but I'd sure like them to be!). But I know it is possible to embed `rgl` into `knitr` documents, but I don't see an easy way to do this with `knit_rd()`. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Edit:

Here's a situation that I'm working on (BASH commands):

```
mkdir matlib-dir
cd matlib-dir
git clone https://github.com/philchalmers/matlib.git
Rscript -e "library('knitr');knit_rd('matlib')"
```

Of the various files generated documents like the `vectors3d.html` contain `rgl` code, but nothing really there because they have not been embedded.

Comment: I have gotten it embedded in html documents. Not sure if it works for anything else.

Comment: See the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879210/including-a-interactive-3d-figure-with-knitr

Comment: Can you post an example maybe?

Comment: @MikeWise updated, and yes I was aware of that like but don't see how it can be incorporated directly

Comment: What do you mean by that? It is embedded in my html document and I can mail it around and people can see it and play with the 3d perspective. That is what I call "embedded".

Comment: All that shows up is the `rgl` code in the generated HTML document, not the actual output generated from it. On the other hand, if something like `plot(1)` is called then that is included in the output. It's just `rgl` output that is not.

Comment: I have no problem getting `rgl` to be embedded into general documents, what I'm asking is whether this can be done for the R help files generated by `knit_rd()`

Comment: I see. I missed the word "help". You should put it in the title.

Comment: Edited. Though it was in the first line of the description ;-P

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't currently possible --- it would need modifications to `knit_rd` to call rglwidget() after each rgl call, or modifications to rglwidget to make that automatic.  I'm working on the latter possibility, but it won't appear soon.