# How to plot3d in the inner plots window of RStudio

Tags: r

I am plotting a 3d graph using `plot3d` {rgl} but it is displayed on an external window frame, and for that reason, it is not captured in the markdown html/pdf file. Is there a way that I can plot the graph in the inner plots window of RStudio so that it can be captured when I compile the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

No.  `rgl` uses a completely different plotting system.  Yihui Xie's [knitr hook documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) explains how to use the `rgl.snapshot()` function to include `rgl` output in a `knitr` document:

```
knit_hooks$set(rgl = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (!before) {
    ## after a chunk has been evaluated
    if (rgl.cur() == 0) return()  # no active device
    name = paste(options$fig.path, options$label, sep = '')
    rgl.snapshot(paste(name, '.png', sep = ''), fmt = 'png')
    return(paste('\\includegraphics{', name, '}\n', sep = ''))
  }
})
```

(then use `rgl=TRUE` in your chunk options). You can also include the output as an [interactive webgl element in an HTML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879210/including-a-interactive-3d-figure-with-knitr).  If you use the `knitr spin` option (see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552276-Creating-Notebooks-from-R-Scripts)), you should be able to include a line like

```
#+ my_rgl_plot, rgl=TRUE
```

before your plot to set the chunk options.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. I tried but in a loop where multiple plots are generated, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? You might need to construct your own code to run `rgl.snapshot` each time and then incorporate the results in the output (i.e., this might be a little too complicated for notebook format, explicitly writing a `.rmd` file might be easier than working within the limitations of the notebook)

Comment: thanks much for your help, I found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664432/how-to-inlcude-multiple-plot3d-in-markdown-knitr-under-a-loop