# How to include multiple plot3d in markdown (knitr) under a loop

Tags: r, knitr

I am plotting a 3d graph using plot3d {rgl} in a loop. knitr rgl hooks works fine for single 3d graph but when used in a loop, markdown file doesn't include 3d graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do it is to use `mfrow3d()` to put multiple "subscenes" in a single "scene", then use the `rglwidget()` command to show the scene in your html. See more information [here](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/talks/2015-12-02/rgl_on_the_web.html#21). Below is a heavily modified version of the script from [Yihui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879210/including-a-interactive-3d-figure-with-knitr):

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
```

Using `mfrow3d()` I create a scene with 5 subscenes,
so each of the 5 plots will appear in a single scene.
Each will still be independently interactive (can zoom in on one at a time, e.g.).

```{r testgl}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)

mfrow3d(nr = 5, nc = 1)
cols <- c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple")
for(i in 1:5){
    plot3d(x, y, z, col = cols[i])
}
rglwidget(height = 4000, width = 1000)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to include multiple `rglwidget()` values.  You need to put them all in a call to `htmltools::tagList()` for this to work.  Modifying Vince's example,

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(rgl)
```

```{r testgl}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)

cols <- c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple")
result <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
    plot3d(x, y, z, col = cols[i])
    result[[i]] <- rglwidget()
}
htmltools::tagList(result)
```
````