# Rayshader in Rmarkdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rayshader

When I render a Rayshader graphic, it pops open Xquartz on my mac, no problem, but what if I wanted to include it in my Rmarkdown document, it just shows the code, no graphic? I understand this is a heavy graphic intensive render, but looking for any tips. thanks, below is my code:

````
---
title: "rayshader"
author: "Daniel"
date: "6/16/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
  self_contained: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r cars}
library(rayshader)

#Here, I load a map with the raster package.
loadzip = tempfile() 
download.file("https://tylermw.com/data/dem_01.tif.zip", loadzip)
localtif = raster::raster(unzip(loadzip, "dem_01.tif"))
unlink(loadzip)

#And convert it to a matrix:
elmat = raster_to_matrix(localtif)

elmat %>%
  sphere_shade(texture = "desert") %>%
  add_water(detect_water(elmat), color = "desert") %>%
  add_shadow(ray_shade(elmat, zscale = 3), 0.5) %>%
  add_shadow(ambient_shade(elmat), 0) %>%
  plot_3d(elmat, zscale = 10, fov = 0, theta = 135, zoom = 0.75, phi = 45, windowsize = c(1000, 800))
```
````

Answer (score 5):

From the package owner:

> To embed the plot into an RMarkdown document, you need to call `rgl::rglwidget()` after bringing up your plot. If you're embedding multiple plots, you will also have to close to previous plot using `rgl::rgl.close()` before plotting the next one.

[reference](https://github.com/tylermorganwall/rayshader/issues/61#issuecomment-531374560)

Worked for me.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the end of your code:

```
Sys.sleep(0.2)
render_snapshot()
```

Comment: It rendered, it but only as a .Jpeg, so I can't use my mouse and move it. I will keep trying tho, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to generate interactive .HTML files of rayshader's 3D renders through the following approach in an R Markdown, using RStudio:

````
title: "title"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output: html_document

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(rayshader)
library(MetBrewer)
library(tidyverse)
library(rgl)

knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
````

The key to embedding the 3D render is on the hook_webgl() function in knitr. The issue is discussed in more length in this thread:

[including a interactive 3D figure with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879210/including-a-interactive-3d-figure-with-knitr)

, including a reference to the alternative `writeWebGL()` function.